# groff ms column break macro

Tags: groff

I have seen here how to perform a page break:

[groff ms page break macro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531215/groff-ms-page-break-macro)

I have been trying to find the equivalent but for columns in a `.2C` two columns formatted document. Sometimes the header of a section appears at the end of the left column isolated and I would like to manually force to appear at the beginning of the right column in those cases.

Is there any equivalent to `.bp` but for columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the basic troff `need` command. It takes the number of lines of space you *need* for the following input.  Typically, a header macro would include such a command to avoid the *widow* that you are seeing. So if you would like at least 2 lines of text plus a header you might use, say

```
.ne 5
```

Comment: Thanks. I have an embeded picture right after the .NH header, maybe that makes the header to appear orphan. In that scenario .ne 5 seems that it does not fix the issue. I have found that header and picture can be enclosed with .KS/.KE and they will be moved to the next column, but I was wondering if a explicit column break command would be available.

Comment: Yes, `.ne 999` will always trigger a new column, but I suppose the `ms` equivalent is the register HORPHANS (lines to keep with header). You could always consider a floating keep `.KF` so that the text stays in column 1 and the image floats to column 2, to avoid big gaps.

Comment: `.ne 999` definitively works, so it is a valid workaround to force a column break